# Conditioning a Function (JS)

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to return a message if one of the argument is not a number. Otherwise continue with the function.
I'm trying this but it's not working as I'm expecting.. ..Please, any help?

```
function findingPairs(arr, value){
            if(isNaN(arr) || isNaN(value)){
                return "Please, introduce just numbers" 
            }
            let sum = 0;
            let finalOutput = [];
            for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
                    let numA = arr[i]
                    console.log(numA)
                } for(let j = 1; j < arr.length; j++){
                    let numB = arr[j]
                    console.log(numB)
                }
            }
        
       findingPairs([1,3,7], 9)
```

Comment: [it's not working as I'm expecting](https://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/) — what happens? What do you expect to happen?

Comment: Sorry I missed to explain that bit. Whether the argument is a number or a string it is always printing "Please, introduce just numbers"

Comment: In the example code you've provided the first argument is neither a number nor a string. It's an array.

Comment: Array of numbers. I just wanted to accept numbers as arguments. 
It is perfectly working!

Comment: An "array of numbers"  isn't "a number", so testing it with `isNaN` is not going to give you the result you want!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Number.isInteger](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isInteger) to check if something is a number.
And [Array.every](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) over the array to check all the array.

Also I'm throwing an Error instead of returning a value because that's what is expected usually.

> [Error Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error)

```js
function findingPairs(arr, value) {
  if (!arr.every(Number.isInteger) || !Number.isInteger(value)) {
    throw new Error("Please, introduce just numbers");
  }

  let sum = 0;
  let finalOutput = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    let numA = arr[i];
    console.log(numA);
  }
  for (let j = 1; j < arr.length; j++) {
    let numB = arr[j];
    console.log(numB);
  }
}

const value = findingPairs([1, 3, 7], 9);
const value2 = findingPairs([1, "a", 7], 9); // Will throw
const value2 = findingPairs([1, 23, 7], "hey"); // Will throw

console.log(value);
```

Comment: Glad to help! Don't forget to choose an answer to the question :D

Answer (score -1):

You need to check if each element of the array is a number, you can use [Array.prototype.some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) to test if one element of the array respects a condition

```js
function findingPairs(arr, value){
    if(arr.some(isNaN) || isNaN(value)){
        return "Please, introduce just numbers" 
    }
    let sum = 0;
    let finalOutput = [];
    for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
            let numA = arr[i]
            console.log(numA)
    } 
    for(let j = 1; j < arr.length; j++){
            let numB = arr[j]
            console.log(numB)
    }
}

findingPairs([1,3,7], 9)
```

Comment: It would be more useful if you linked some docs or give a runnable example.